# I can't turn off dropbox autostart

Tags: dropbox, autostart

Dropbox keeps automatically starting on my Ubuntu system, and I can't turn it off. It is installed directly in my home directory (not via Snap or APT).

Dropbox starts automatically upon system boot, even though I tried disabling and deleting it in the Startup Applications and manually killed the process. Each time I manually open Dropbox, it re-enables itself in Startup Applications. I tried modifying and deleting the .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/, but it gets recreated by Dropbox each time I open the app manually.

I don't know how to go to settings of the app from the system. There is an app symbol on the upper pannel on my desktop but it is neither left nor right clickable. I don't think that going to settings from the webbrowser will be helpful.

> Dropbox daemon version: 187.4.5691
>
> Dropbox command-line interface version: 2023.09.06
>
> Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `Dropbox` drop down menu from the system tray and navigate down to `Preferences`

[image]

After which uncheck the option to Start Dropbox on system startup.

Comment: The dropbox icon on the system tray was neither left-clickable nor right-clickable... until just now...
Your solution worked, thanks.